# How to have a quiet execution of a file in binary table during the InstallUISequence?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a file which is not installed:

```
<Binary Id="LaunchMyExe" SourceFile="$(var.Project.DependenciesPath)/myProgram.exe" />
```

And I would like to run it quietly during the InstallUISequence but I can't..
How to link the BinaryKey of this file to the CAQuietExec custom action?
Any sample appreciated.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to author another custom action, which will extract that file from Binary and place to some folder known to your "LaunchMyExe" action, for instance, Temp folder.

Comment: Thx. using the Windows Installer database API or is there a much simpler solution?

Comment: If you can afford the dependency on the .NET (for instance, if you app requires .NET and you have it as a prerequisite), you can take advantage of DTF - the .NET wrapper on top of Windows Installer API, which is nice and well-designed and is deployed together with WiX.

Comment: If I create a CA in C#, I will need some dependencies (extra home made C# DLLs)... How can I manage these DLLs to be able to run my CA? (How my CA will locate the DLLs?)

Comment: That's a good question. To be honest - I don't know, I've never created CA with a dependency to an external DLL which should be pulled...

Answer (score 0):

Is your program a console application? If it's a *regular GUI* application, you, most probably, don't need CAQuietExec action because you can run it directly with [`CustomAction`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) element.

Set these properties:

- `BinaryKey="LaunchMyExe"` - this is the key into the `Binary` table where your exe is stored.
- `ExeCommand=""` - this tells WiX and Windows Installer you want [**type 2** custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa372048.aspx).
- set other properties as appropriate.

If your application is a *console* one, then you would need [WiX Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) to hide the console window while it runs.

These links would help you:

- [**Quiet Execution Custom Action**](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) gives examples on how to use `QtExec` action.
- [How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm) for an overview on using custom actions.